# How to remove actionbar on android?

Tags: java, android

I have an Android project, and I can't remove the action bar.  Please help me.

I tried this :

```
Android:theme=@android:style/theme.holo.noactionbar.fullscreen"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to know your minSdkVersion. but you can use these steps :
change your project theme

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
    ...
</application>
```

and add this code to your onCreate action on your mainjava

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
```

it needs this import file too :

```
import android.view.*;
```